# React - How to handle nested forms and its value

Tags: reactjs

I have to setup one form which have nested values in single form
Basically I need to send data in below format to API

```
Payload: {"name": "The org name", "detail": "The org detail", "attributes": {"address": {"lines":[], "city":"", "state": "", "country": "India", "zip": ""}, "contacts":[{"name": "abc", "phone": "PH"}, {"name": "x", "phone": "PH"}] }}
```

I used react-bootstrap for handling forms.

below are the currrent code of my form

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = this.getInitialState();
  }
  getInitialState() {
    const initialState = {
      organizationForm: {
        name: '',
        detail: '',
        type: 'org',
        attributes: {
          contacts: [{
            name: '',
            phone: ''
          }],
          address: {
            lines: [],
            city: '',
            state: '',
            country: '',
            zip: ''
          }
        }
      },
      errors: {}
    };

    return initialState;
  }

handleChange(e) {
    const organizationForm = this.state.organizationForm;
    var key = e.target.name;
    var value = e.target.value;
    organizationForm[key] = value;
    this.setState({
      organizationForm
    });
  }
```

Below are the code of form

```
  <Col className="create-content-wrap" sm={12}>
        <form className="">
          <FormGroup className="custom-form-group required row">
            <ControlLabel className="custom-form-control-label col-sm-3">
              Name
            </ControlLabel>
            <FormControl
              className="custom-form-control col-sm-9"
              type="text"
              name="name"
              value={organizationForm.name}
              onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
            />
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup className="custom-form-group required row">
            <ControlLabel className="custom-form-control-label col-sm-3">
              Detail
            </ControlLabel>
            <FormControl
              className="custom-form-control col-sm-9"
              type="text"
              name="detail"
              componentClass="textarea"
              value={organizationForm.detail}
              onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
            />
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup className="custom-form-group row">
            <ControlLabel className="custom-form-control-label col-sm-3">
              Address
            </ControlLabel>
            <FormControl
              className="custom-form-control col-sm-9"
              type="text"
              name="lines"
              componentClass="textarea"
              value={organizationForm.lines}
              onChange={this.handleAddressChange.bind(this)}
            />
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup className="custom-form-group row">
            <ControlLabel className="custom-form-control-label col-sm-3">
              City
            </ControlLabel>
            <FormControl
                className="custom-form-control col-sm-9"
                type="text"
                name="city"
                value={organizationForm.attributes.address.city}
                onChange={this.handleAddressChange.bind(this)}
            />
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup className="custom-form-group row">
            <ControlLabel className="custom-form-control-label col-sm-3">
              State
            </ControlLabel>
            <FormControl
              className="custom-form-control col-sm-9"
              type="text"
              name="state"
              value={organizationForm.attributes.address.state}
              onChange={this.handleAddressChange.bind(this)}
            />
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup className="custom-form-group row">
            <ControlLabel className="custom-form-control-label col-sm-3">
              Country
            </ControlLabel>
            <FormControl
              className="custom-form-control col-sm-9"
              type="text"
              name="country"
              value={organizationForm.attributes.address.country}
              onChange={this.handleAddressChange.bind(this)}
            />
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup className="custom-form-group row">
            <ControlLabel className="custom-form-control-label col-sm-3">
              Zipcode
            </ControlLabel>
            <FormControl
              className="custom-form-control col-sm-9"
              type="number"
              name="zip"
              value={organizationForm.attributes.address.zip}
              onChange={this.handleAddressChange.bind(this)}
            />
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup className="custom-form-group row">
            <ControlLabel className="custom-form-control-label col-sm-3">
              Contacts
            </ControlLabel>
            <FormControl
              className="custom-form-control col-sm-9"
              type="number"
              name="contacts"
              value={organizationForm.attributes.contacts}
              onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
            />
          </FormGroup>
        </form>
      </Col>
```

I am noobie in react js world. How can i bind nested fields of address and contacts ?

Comment: `organizationForm[key] = value;` don't mutate state directly

Comment: Its working fine for single field . like name,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add couple of methods to handle for address and attributes like below
Way - 1

```
<FormControl
      className="custom-form-control col-sm-9"
      type="text"
      name="city"
      value={organizationForm.attributes.address.city}
      onChange={this.handleAddressChange(this)}
 />

handleAddressChange = (e) => {
    const organizationForm = this.state.organizationForm;
    let address = organizationForm.attributes.address;
    var key = e.target.name;
    var value = e.target.value;
    address[key] = value;
    organizationForm.attributes.address = address;
    this.setState({
      organizationForm
    });
  }
```

This way your form is loosely coupled also . So if any change happens in the child object will not affect the other one. Similarly you can add for all the nested objects like address, attribute etc.

Way - 2

You can do the same by below but you need to handle which object your modifing with in the same method .

```
<FormControl
          className="custom-form-control col-sm-9"
          type="text"
          name="city"
          value={organizationForm.attributes.address.city}
          onChange={event => { this.handleChange(event, this.state.organizationForm.attributes.address  ,'address'); }}
     />

     <FormControl
          className="custom-form-control col-sm-9"
          type="text"
          name="city"
          value={organizationForm.attributes.address.city}
          onChange={event => { this.handleChange(event, this.state.organizationForm.attributes.contacts  ,'contacts'); }}
     />


     <FormControl
          className="custom-form-control col-sm-9"
          type="text"
          name="city"
          value=onChange={event => { this.handleChange(event, this.state.organizationForm ,'organizationForm'); }}
     />


    handleChange = (e , object , type) => {
        const organizationForm = this.state.organizationForm;
        var key = e.target.name;
        var value = e.target.value;
        object[key] = value;
        if(type === 'address'){
            organizationForm.attributes.address = object;
        } else if (type === 'contacts'){
            organizationForm.attributes.contacts = object;
        } 
        this.setState({
          organizationForm : organizationForm
        });
      }
```

Comment: Thank you so much Abdul, its working great. but i also asked how to handle dynamic form of contacts. it has multiple nested array . do you have idea how to do it ?

Comment: @Vishal You could make a `Contacts` component to deal with that part.

Comment: can you post me the form . I cant give you any info without the form structure . I added way 2 also for you .

Comment: @Abdul i am implementing your second method

Comment: if your following first method . You need to add one more method to handle contacts like you added for address. what you mean by dynamic form of contacts (will it change for different request) . because form structure should be constant right

Comment: @Abdul  Dynamic form means, contact will have multiple address and phone like this `"contacts":[{"name": "abc", "phone": "PH"}, {"name": "x", "phone": "PH"}] ` , while implementing second method, i got compile error Syntax error: "organizationForm" is read-only

Comment: You need to pass the form from state . this.state.organizationForm & this.state.organizationForm.attributes.contacts like this while calling the method .  So you need to handle list of contacts ? Do you have any readonly property in contacts to identify the contact

Comment: Yes, i need to handle list of contacts.

Comment: Do you have any readonly property in contacts to identify the contact like id or name etc . if you can find the same means we can achieve it , if not its really hard to do it

Comment: @Abdul Contacts have name and phone fileds. what do you mean by readonly property . it has name and phone fields . i need to pass array of those fields to API

Comment: @Abdul it can be duplicated,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179613/discussion-between-vishal-and-abdul).

Comment: Using var should be avoided. Start using let and const everywhere

Answer (score 5):

I suggest that you keep your component state flat, just one key for each field in the form. When you submit the form, then you can format it into the shape necessary for the API.

Answer (score 1):

This might not work for all cases, but it worked for me and might be helpful to anyone searching this now. I had a form that rendered different input elements, but it also rendered a button that opened up a modal component with a form unrelated to the larger form surrounding it. To solve the problem of this nested form: first, I removed the form elements in the modal (the `<form>`) and left just the `<input>` inside the component. Then, in that  element, I added:

`onChange = {e => setValue(e.target.value)}`

After this, I made a state variable that looked like this: `const [value, setValue] = useState("");`. And finally, I added a button under the input with something like `onClick={handleSubmit}` and defined a function that submitted the form with `value` as the result of the form submission.

So essentially, I replaced the internal state of the nested form with React state, removed the form elements and kept the input, and then created a button that would handle my submission. That way, I bypassed having nested forms by just having an input element instead of a full form.

Answer (score 0):

This will help in a better way ...
Suppose you have a student like below

```
export type Guardian = {
  aadhaarId: string;
  name: string;
  phoneNo: number;
  address: string;
};

export type Student = {
  ...

  guardian: Guardian;
  
};
```

You can update guardian like below ...

```
      <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="gName">
        <Form.Label>Name</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
          type="text"
          placeholder="Guardian Name"
          onChange={(e) =>
            setStudent({
              ...student,
              guardian: { ...student.guardian, name: e.target.value },
            })
          }
        />
      </Form.Group>
```